# How to animate a polygon mask with performance?

Tags: iphone, uiview

I'm having a performance issue.

I've created an UIView and overwrited it's drawRect function. At this function, I was drawing an image (big one), and over that, an white square at the entire screen with a polygon inside it, with CGContextEOFillPath. The result is an white screen with portion of the image (defined by the polygon) displayed.

After that, I created a function to animate the transition of that polygon to another one. Besides the polygon animation, the image should also be scaled and moved to fix the diplayed at the screen. I did that with an NSTimer. The animation of the polygon consists in calculating the distance between each vertex and moving then to a position according to elapsedTime. It worked just fine at the simulator, but got really stucked at device.

Reading about performance, here at stackoverflow, I found the alternative to use beginAnimations and commitAnimations. I'm changing everything to use that approach with the image. But what can I do with the polygon. The polygon is drawn with CGContextMoveToPoint and CGContextAddLineToPoint, so I believe it can't be animated with beginAnimations. An I correct? Is there a better approach to do that?

The desired result is something like this comic reader app: http://www.comixology.com/iphoneapp (click on guided tour. at the middle of the video they show the "automatic masking" feature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a [CAShapeLayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) overlaid on your main image view, with the CAShapeLayer being the size of the view you want to mask and having a polygon path for a hole in the center of it.  CAShapeLayers let you animate from one CGPathRef to another smoothly, as long as the two paths have the same number of control points.  You will need to use a CABasicAnimation here to do that animating, rather than a UIView begin / commitAnimations block, but it's not too difficult.

Joe Ricioppo has a nice example of animating CAShapeLayer paths in his post [here](http://tumbljack.com/post/179975074/complex-interpolation-with-cashapelayer-free).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this approach first and if I don't get successfull, I'll give Adrian's one a try. After that I hate the answers, ok? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With Core Animation you can animate "animatable" (sic) properties. Apple's documentation enumerates animatable properties in Mac OS X:

http://url.akosma.com/55

In the case of the iPhone, the UIView documentation explicitly says "animatable" when a given property is, hum, animatable. The most powerful of these are (IMHO) UIView's "transform" property, which takes CGAffineTransform structs as inputs, or CALayer's "transform" property (which takes CATransform3D structs). Both are animatable and give you tremendous power to create any kind of transition you want.

Now, in your case, indeed, you can't animate the polygon in an "easy" way. My bet would be in your case to try to map CGAffineTransforms that fit your needs (scale, translation) and apply that to a fixed view, non-animated, created using your Quartz code.

I hope I'm clear enough :)